# how to use use android library in react native?

Tags: react-native

How to use android third party library in react native to test its UI in react native.The 3rd party library is related to recyclerview which forms recyclerViewPager. Now, will it be a native UI compenent or native Module??

Comment: You should elaborate a little which 3rd party library you're using. Usually you need to configure `build.gradle`, `settings.gradle`, `MainActivity.java` and perhaps `AndroidManifest.xml` to get external libraries / components to work. These steps are usually described somewhere. Also `rnpm link` could help you with the process.

Comment: @zvona: com.github.lsjwzh.RecyclerViewPager:lib:v1.1.0-beta5 is the library i am using. It is like custamized recyclerview. To use it in react native what process should i follow? please suggest some examples or tutorial to understand clearly, other than official doc.

Comment: Oh, it's Android library without RN support. Then you should search for Android library development for React Native and make it yourself RN compatible. This is all I could find about the implementation: https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager#usage